# Why do we constantly refer to gold generating items as "GP5" (Gold Per 5) when they actually generate 5 gold per 10 seconds?

Tags: league-of-legends

Or am I simply wrong about what the acronym GP5 stands for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because we're used to the other acronyms of HP5 and MP5, and well, 5GP10 is too weird.

Comment: That makes sense, everything else that is per-time seems to be a "per 5 Seconds".

Answer (score 1):

People do call them gp10s quite frequently, but I believe that before they used to generate it per 5 seconds and then they changed it to 10 seconds for convenience. Old-schoolers still call it gp5s I guess!